# What is the equivalent of hook_user with $op='form' in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, hooks, users

What is the equivalent of `hook_user` with `$op = 'form'` in Drupal 7?
 According to the documentation of `hook_user`, `'form'` means:

> form: The user account edit form is about to be displayed. The module should present the form elements it wishes to inject into the form.

But I couldn't find any equivalent hook in Drupal 7 [`user.api.php`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.api.php/7).

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[hook_form_user_profile_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state)](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7)
I think its what you need